# Reading input commands with up to 3 commands

Tags: c++, eclipse, command, cin

I have a program which prompts the user to input a command. Based on the command, it will perform different functions.

example commands:

```
help
set value 20
set another 30
print this
print that
```

How can I split these into 3 separate variables and continue the program? I'm having trouble with a simple

```
string command;
string item;
string value;
cin >> command >> item >> value;
```

Because unless the user inputs all three, the program won't continue.

### This is what I came up with, I can't answer my own question so this will do.

Thank you for the input. This is what I came up with after researching some of those functions mentioned by @JoachimPileborg. It seems to work just how I need it.

```
int main() {

    bool done = false;
    char input[30];
    std::string command, item, value;

    //output instructions, get user input
    std::cout << "Type 'help' to find more about commands.\n";
    do{

    std::cin.getline(input,30);

    //parse user input from char to an array
    istringstream iss;
    string commands[3];
    iss.str (input);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        iss >> commands[i];
    }

    //set each part of the array to appropriate value
    command = commands[0];
    item = commands[1];
    value = commands[2];

    //properly sort out which command is being called
    //first: check if command has 3 parts
    if (commands[2].length() != 0){
        cout << command << item << value;
    }
    //second:if it doesnt have 3 parts, check if it has 2 parts
    else if (commands[1].length() != 0){
        cout << command << item;
    }
    //third:if it doesn't have 2 parts, check for 1 part
    else if (commands[0].length() != 0){
        if (command == "help"){
            commandline.help();
            done = true;
        }
        else{
        cout << "Incorrect Command! Please try again!";
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "No command found, please try again!";
    }while(!done);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the input operator `>>` when reading things like command lines. Instead I suggest you to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to put the separate strings into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You can read the entire line into a string, and split the string based on a space delimiter. Then depending on how many words your string splits into, continue from there.

Comment: To further help you, store the command names and [function objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), then it's easy to find the function to call for a specific command. Pass the vector containing the command line to the function as argument, similar in how `argv` is passed to your `main` function.

Comment: @Ben how do you read the whole line into a string if it has spaces?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm very new to c++ and i'm not very familiar with any of these functions, I will look into them. Can you provide any examples?

Comment: You should read the documentation for the functions cited

Comment: @phillipppp Why `char input[30];` and not simply `std:string input;`? Did you try the code I have proposed in my answer? IMHO that's more concise and straightforward. Please ask, if you miss something from the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> "How can I split these into 3 separate variables and continue the program?"

Don't have distinct variables, use an appropriate standard library container to collect a variable number of parameters given for a command.

The very simplest way,- I can imagine -, how to implement such thing, would probably look like this:

```
std::string cmdline;

while(cmdline != "quit") {
    std::cout << "Enter command > ";
    std::getline(std::cin),cmdline);
    if(!cmdline.empty()) {
        std::istringstream iss(cmdline);
        std::vector<std::string> cmditems;
        std::string cmditem;
        while(iss >> cmditem) {
            cmditems.push_back(cmditem);
        }
        if(cmditems.empty()) { // Just whitespaces input
            continue; 
        }
        // accessing cmditems[0] is always safe at this point
        if(cmditems[0] == "help") {
            printHelp();
        }
        else if(cmditems[0] == "set") {
            // Check if the number of command arguments actually 
            // fit the required ones
            if(cmditems.size() < 3) { 
                std::cerr << "Please enter a name and value!" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            setValue(cmditems[1],cmditems[2]);
        }
        else if(cmditems[0] == "print") {
            // Check if the number of command arguments actually 
            // fit the required ones
            if(cmditems.size() < 2) {
                std::cerr << "Please enter a name to print!" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            printValue(cmditems[1]);
        }
        // and so on ...
    }        
}
```